# Colormap to grayscale tif image in java

Tags: java, tiff, color-scheme, geotiff

I have a gray scale tiff image.Now i want to add some pseudo colors i.e for pixels whose DN from 0-140, red color;DN from 141-255 ,blue color.Please tell me how to modify the raster table.Otherwise if you have any other solution,please let me know.

Comment: how to accept previous answers to questions.

Comment: @SureshKumar You can go to your [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1264167/suresh-kumar?tab=questions), go to the various questions you asked and accept answers if they helped you solve your issues. To accept an answer, check the links provided above.